# Ajax and PHP return data to table cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

New to PHP/MySQL here and I have been trying to learn some Ajax.

I want to return some JSON (one figure e.g `12345`) to a `$variable` and `echo` this variable in in a single table cell. (There may be better ways to do this however I just want to know how it's done - if at all possible!)

So far I can retrieve the JSON figure and display it within a `<div id="result"></div>` using the code below, so I know the request works - I'm just stuck at passing the variable part.

My response (in Chrome) looks like this;

[image]

My code so far is;

**chartAjax.php**

```
<form method="post" id="search">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="result"></div> <!-- this successfully displays the figure on submit -->

<table id="datatable" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <td>{NEED TO echo the $result here}</td> <!-- stuck here -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**monthConn.php**

```
<?php 

/* set header type to json */
header('Content-Type: application/json');

/* array to pass back data */
$data = array();

/* get date from form submit */
if (isset($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['date'])){$date = $_POST['date'];}

/* Create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM transactions WHERE TimeStamp >= ?");

/* Bind parameters */
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $date);

/* Execute it */
$stmt -> execute();

/* Bind results */
$stmt -> bind_result($data);

/* fetch values */
$stmt->fetch();

 /* close conn */
$stmt->close();

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

My **JS** (contained within chartAjax.php page above)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        /* Clear result div*/
        $("#result").html('');

        /* Get from elements values */
        var values = $(this).serialize();

        ajaxRequest= $.ajax({
            url: "monthConn.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            success: function(response, data) {
            if(data == "success") {
              $("#result").html(response); //add response to results div
            }
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Apologies if the code/methodology is very amateur, any help or suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: what is your data/response looks like?

Comment: That is not json at all, this is just text. json is key value pair like `{key:value}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

add this (AS count)

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT count(*) AS count FROM transactions WHERE TimeStamp >= ?");
```

then apply this

```
//just incase you want to return more than 1 value in the future
return json_encode(array('count' => $data));
```

then in your

```
if(data == "success") {
    var return_data = $.parseJSON(response);

    $("#datatable").html(return_data['count']);
}

<table id="datatable" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <td id="response"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you print_r your $data?

Comment: can you then get it from your ajax to your response td? ah yes you are right. but for me i usually just return it because i return the value to the caller.

Comment: have you change your the <td id="response"></td>?

Comment: do remember that  php is server side code, when you return to frontend which is javascript you should use javascript variable instead of php variable, so $var is no longer viable for this case.

Comment: You are still using datatable instead of response https://jsfiddle.net/p4emh1m9/2/

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting an element with id result to show your response, please update the td id

```
<form method="post" id="search">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



<table id="datatable" class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <td id="result">{RETURNED JSON FIGURE HERE}</td> <!-- stuck here -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```